# Facebook Timeout Limitation

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention

My company is building out a platform that will be syndicating content to several thousand pages at one time. How can we do this without being marked as spam? Additionally, what can we do to apply for an account manager that we can work with more closely?

Here are the current concerns:

1. Posts could require hours / days to complete at this scale (because of the needed delay between posts to prevent the posts being marked as spam ***)
2. Facebook could potentially black list our platform altogether because of a misunderstanding regarding the nature of the syndicated content
3. Lastly, we have a strong desire to acquire a Facebook Account Manager to assist us in maintaining compliance.

*** Please note, the pages that are receiving this content are all opted in to the platform. These are business pages started by unique individuals within a company representing a single brand.

Best Regards

Comment: What does syndicate content to several thousands of pages mean? What content? Who writes the content? Are the content unique for each page or are you publishing the same thing on all pages? That the pages opted in doesn't effect if it is spam or not.

Comment: Syndicating content meaning posting statuses with pre-defined content (e.g. a story, a product, etc.)

Comment: The same content on several pages?